# Jenkins Version upgrade from 2.164.3 to 2.235.5

Tags: jenkins

The current version of the Jenkins that my clients are using is **2.164.3** and they asked me to upgrade it to the latest which currently is **2.235.5**. We have a lot of pipelines ( both normal and multi-branch ) and a few freestyle jobs.

Will there be any issue If I migrate? Will all the jobs work the same or is there any chance that the pipelines break due to the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pipeline could break. Maybe good starting point for you is look for plugins. How many and what are the plugins your pipelines are using. I would highly recommend first create new Jenkins instance for testing with new version and run your few production pipelines on the new Jenkins instance so, that you will get an idea if it's breaking something or not. if it's breaking then figure it out why it's breaking so could be plugin issue or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the plugins you got if those are still compatible with the new version of Jenkins and given there are plugins inter-dependencies as well one can't be certain unless he tests it. It is a big jump if I look at the Jenkins versions you have specified. I would highly recommend you to first test that on a test Instance before you upgrade in production.

Answer (score 1):

It is usefull to read [changelogs](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.176.1) to understand what was changed/added/deleted.

Also there is nice [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/). Just start reading from 2.176.x.

Main point from my experience (I've updated jenkins from 1.652.x to 2.x version and I'm doing it continuously): make backup of main config.xml file which stored in $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml before any updates or changes.

Also it is usefull to make full backup of $JENKINS_HOME folder.

If you will not update jenkins' plugins - all jobs should work as before.

Beginning with Jenkins LTS release 2.235.3, stable repositories will be signed with the same GPG keys that sign the weekly repositories. Administrators of Linux systems must install the new signing keys on their Linux servers before installing Jenkins 2.235.3.

Debian/Ubuntu

```
# wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -
```

Red Hat/CentOS

```
# rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
```

Also all your agents which are using JNLP v1,2,3 could become unavailable, since jenkins turning these protocols off. After update you will need to activate them manually.

I recommend you to update java version. For me it is 8u262 if I'm not mistaken. And set java memory limits for jenkins:

CentOS example:

```
/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512M -Xmx512M"
```

Ubuntu example:

```
/etc/default/jenkins
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms512M -Xmx512M"
```

Main problem goes with updating plugins. Since much changelogs needs to be read before update, just like with jenkins itself.

So, good luck in updating jenkins.